# How to search the XML tag?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to search the tags in XML. 
My XML is:-

```
<school>
  <student>
    <firstname>Vijay</firstname>
    <lastname>Prabhu</lastname>
    <age>27</age>
    <photo>/NewExample;component/Images/icon_man.png</photo>
  </student>
  <student>
    <firstname>Arun</firstname>
    <lastname>Prasath</lastname>
    <age>5</age>
    <photo>/NewExample;component/Images/icon_man.png</photo>
  </student>
  <student>
    <firstname>Satheesh</firstname>
    <lastname>Kumar</lastname>
    <age>27</age>
  </student> 
</school>
```

Here I want to check `<photo>` tag is available or not.
I have try like this.

```
  var school= from ack in xdoc.Descendants("school")
                           select ack;
for(int i =0;i<school.count();i++)
{
  if(school.ElementAt(i).Element("photo").Name.LocalName.Equals("photo"));
    Console.WriteLine("Tag is available in==>"+i);
  else
    Console.WriteLine("Tag is Not available in==>"+i);
}
```

It is working. But when I use this same in another example with diff elements it showing error.
Please let me know any other effective way to search the Tags in c#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a rather odd use of LINQ and IEnumerable... Do you need to retrieve the index specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all students. Then try to retrieve `photo` element from `student` element. If it is equal to `null` then photo no exist in current student:

```
var students = xdoc.Root.Elements("student");
int i = 1;
string format = "Tag is {0}available in {1}";

foreach(var student in students)
   Console.WriteLine(format, student.Element("photo") == null ? "not " : "",i++);
```

Output:

```
Tag is available in 1
Tag is available in 2
Tag is not available in 3
```

---

You can write extension to make code more readable

```
public static bool HasElement(this XElement parent, XName name)
{
    return parent.Element(name) != null;
}
```

E.g. selecting all students which have photo will look like

```
from student in xdoc.Root.Elements("student")
where student.HasElement("photo")
select student
```

You also can use XPath for same task

```
xdoc.XPathSelectElements("school/student[photo]")
```